# Blender Physics Simulation is Weird

Tags: add-on, physics, collision, soft-body

First of all sorry for my english. I'm trying to make physics based short animation in blender. I'm using molecular addon but simulation isn't correct. It always pass the collision even at 16 mol_substep. When i try to do it in C4D it's tottaly awesome. But i should use blender for gpu rendering. I have a decent gpu and bad cpu. Anyone can help me ? (last image is a c4d - i want to achieve that with blender)

[image: Blender]

[image: C4D]